# Infopath and XML file

Tags: xml, infopath, infopath2010, gpo

I have a GPO that blocks all applications from opening except for those listed in the GPO. I am trying to double-click an XML file which is set to open with Infopath. Infopath is in the list of allowed applications. Why would I get this alert? If I open Infopath and use it to open the file it works fine. In case you are assuming it is trying to open with Internet Explorer, that is also in the list of allowed applications.

Comment: Is the file actually a saved InfoPath form or just a plain XML file?

Comment: It is an XML file created using InfoPath.